# How to run Derric

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to run Derric with command

```
import lang::derric::testparse;
```

I followed all instructions and got everything to work with eclipse and Rascal. I am running the rascal console with Derric. I have tried downloading older versions of eclipse, used windows 7, and windows 10. Nothing is working, I even read the rascal tutorial on modules to see if everything looks right and it does.  I need it to work for a school assignment, if someone can get it to run can you tell me under which circumstances (i.e eclipse version, windows version, steps taken) to run the program?

```
rascal>import lang::derric::testparse;

Error: Cannot import module lang::derric::testparse

Time: 484ms
ok

rascal>
```

It's suppose to say ok at the end, and then I can run command generate().

Answer (score 1):

Hi @yoyo great that you are trying Rascal, but you need to give more explanation about what you are trying to do. There are potentially two main causes of the message you get:

- the module is correct but it cannot be found, or
- the module is incorrect (e.g. it does not even parse correctly).

It would therefore be helpful if you show

- where `lang::derric::testparse` is located in your file system, and
- to show its contents.

As a side question: is there any relation with the Derric language (a DSL for file formats)  Jeroen van den Bos has been working on a few years ago?

Comment: the module is correct but it cannot be found. The file is located under C:\User\Chris\eclipse-workspace\derric\derric\src\lang\derric\testparse.rsc

Comment: I am working on the Derric language, I just have no idea how to run it.